# To what level is this schema normalized?

Tags: database-normalization

```
logical design: 
Pet(name, type, birthday, cost)

determinants:
name->type
name->birthday
name->cost
```

Here is some data:

```
name   type   birthday   cost
Bruno  cat    1/1/1982   free
Poppy  cat    1/2/1982   20.00
Silly  cat    12/2/1995  free
Sam    dog    2/3/1989   100.00
Tuffy  dog    3/3/1974   free
```

There's repeated data between rows but no duplicate columns. I think it's in BCNF.

Comment: Those are not "determinants", they are FDs. Find out what FDs & determinants are. The NF cannot be known unless we know more about those FD, like that they are a cover. Please read & act on [ask] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show your work following the steps in your textbook. PS What does "I think" mean? If you can't answer the question, you don't have  a reason to think that you have an opinion.

Comment: What does "repeated data between rows" mean & why do you think it matters? What does "no duplicate columns" mean & why do you think it matters?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the schema is in BCNF, if the dependencies given are a cover of all the dependencies holding in the schema. In this case, `name` is the only candidate key, and the left part of each non-trivial dependency (including those implied by the cover) is a super key. So the relation is in BCNF.